# В чем разница между ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException и IndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java, исключения

В чем разница между ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException и IndexOutOfBoundsException?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если обратиться к официальной документации этих исключений и попробовать их сравнить:

[`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html)

> Thrown to indicate that an array has been accessed with an illegal index. The index is either negative or greater than or equal to the size of the array.

и [`IndexOutOfBoundsException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html):

> Thrown to indicate that an index of some sort (such as to an array, to a string, or to a vector) is out of range.
>   Applications can subclass this class to indicate similar exceptions.

То можно сказать, что первое исключение возникает в момент обращение к массиву с некорректным индексом, т.е. например, `array[-1]`. А второе возникает, если происходит попытка обратиться к какой то коллекции, с некорректным индексом. Т.е. подразумевается какая то проверка на корректность индекса в какой то структуре данных, помимо массива,  в результате которой и возбужается `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

Answer (score 7):

**ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException** - обращение к несуществующему индексу массива. Например, попытка взять значение **array[5]** из массива **int[4]**.

**IndexOutOfBoundsException** - попытка использования несуществующего индекса, например, при выделении подстроки **substring(2,6)** из строкового значения **string** длиной 4 символа.

Comment: Во втором примере выйдет Exception: StringIndexOutOfBoundsException