# Код выдает ошибку

Tags: java

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        for (int i = -3 * n / 2; i <= n; i++) {
            for (int j = -3 * n / 2; j <= 3 * n / 2; j++) {

                if ((Math.abs(i) + Math.abs(j) < n)
                        || ((-n / 2 - i) * (-n / 2 - i) + (n / 2 - j) * (n / 2 - j) <= n * n / 2)
                        || ((-n / 2 - i) * (-n / 2 - i) + (n / 2 - j) * (-n / 2 - j) <= -n * n / 2)) {
                    System.out.println("* ");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("* ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Новичок в программировании, язык Java. Пытаюсь что-то исправить код опять выдает ошибку. Первая была: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:6)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [В чем разница между ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException и IndexOutOfBoundsException?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/721001/%d0%92-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-%d0%b8-indexoutofboundsexception)

Comment: вы знаете, что это код делает?

Comment: @Kristina Вроде же очевидно по ошибке, что размер String[] args у Вас равен нулю, а вы хотите получить из него первый элемент. Проверьте свои входные данные.

Answer (score 0):

Можете вместо `args[0]` засунуть

```
Scanner scanner - new Scanner(System.in);
int n = scanner.nextInt();
```

И тогда не придется с входными параметраи париться. Просто при запуске с `args` аргументы - это какой-то массив строк вводимый при запуске команды, например: `java -jar MyProgram.java 1 2 3`
Или можете перехватить исключение и вывести сообщение о том что массив пуст:

```
try {
int n = ...
...
} catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
System.out.println("Your array is empty!")
}
```